# Problems with generating config files with tox

Tags: openstack, tox

I'm following the installation guide of Sahara - OpenStack.
[install-with-fuel](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/sahara/userdoc/installation.guide.html#to-install-with-fuel)

After setting up an OpenStack cloud using RDO quickstart, I installed the openstack-sahara and started the configuration phase. So I followed this oficial document.
 ([sahara-userdoc](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/sahara/userdoc/configuration.guide.html)).

But when I tried to generate a new conf file using `tox -e genconfig`, I got this error:

```
ERROR: toxini file 'tox.ini' not found
```

My machine have Centos7 and my tox version is 2.1.1 (imported from `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tox/__init__.pyc`).

Comment: Are you sure that you run the tox command in the directory, where the `tox.ini` file containing the genconfig environment is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tox -egenconfig needs all source code, which means the git repository, not the binary source code path

I think you just need a sample config file, if your binary package doesn't install it for you, I think you need to install git and download sahara git repository then generate it by your hands, it will be a bit inconvenient if you are not a developer (or don't have any developer workmate)

```
cd /some/path/you/prefer
sudo apt-get install git git-core
git clone http://github.com/openstack/sahara
cd sahara
git checkout master (or stable/liberty, stable/kilo etc)
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install -U tox
tox -egenconfig
```